# Get average value from EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I got two tables `Student` and `Course`.

The table `Course` uses `StudentId` as FK key. Inside `Course` table there's `Score` for each course the student have taken.

Now, how do I calculate the total average `Score` related to `StudentId`?

This is how far I got(`Id` = Students id):

```
var avg = db.Courses.Where(c=> c.StudentId == Id ... ?
```

**Edit:** The `Course` table have some `null` in `Score` for unfinished cources.

Comment: Use a `.GroupBy()` to group `Courses` by `StudentId` and then average the scores (you need to give more information on your models)

Comment: You don't have a courses collection on the student? That would be more intuitive I'd say

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Yes I do, if you mean `ICollection<Cource>` in model.

Comment: var avg = db.Courses.Where(c => c.StudentId == Id && c.Score != null).Select(c => c.Score).Average();

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nkosis solution worked. But I'm still curious how this is solved by `.GroupBy()`. I replaced `Where` with `GroupBy` but I not sure what to do with`.Average();`, wont work at the end of the syntax.

Comment: The `.GroupBy()` would be used if you wanted to get the average for each student - i.e to return a list of all students and their associated average score for each course. It was not clear what you meant by _Students ids_ (plural) :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Aah I meant singular! Sorry for my poor grammar. Thank you for the clarification :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Source: [Return the Average Value From a Numeric Sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399409(v=vs.110).aspx)

Given that a score can be null then you should only take records that have a valid score

```
var avg = db.Courses
            .Where(c => c.StudentId == Id && c.Score != null)
            .Average(c => c.Score);
```

If you looking for an average score per student, then you can use both `GroupBy` and `Average`.

```
var avgerages = db.Courses
                  .Where(c => c.Score != null)
                  .GroupBy(g => g.StudentId, c => c.Score )
                  .Select(g => new 
                   {
                       StudentId = g.Key,
                       Average = g.Average()
                   });
```